# Authenticated encryption vs end-end encryption

Tags: encryption, authenticated-encryption

I am kind of new to crypto. can someone highlight the differences between authenticated encryption and End-to-End encryption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Authenticated encryption is an all-in-one encryption form (algorithm) that provides privacy, integrity, and authenticity together.

End-to-end encryption is a concept where only end-users read the encrypted message. end-to-end encryption aims to prevent man-in-the-middle eavesdrop such as telecom and internet providers. The transit data in the servers are encrypted and the service owners do not have keys and the possibility to decrypt it.

they are totally different.

Comment: And just to be clear "authenticated" means that you can determine if the encrypted data has bee modified or not.  It does not tell you that Alice either encrypted the data or sent it, that happens at a higher level.